# Parsing RSS Feed XML using PHP -> Cannot get iTunes:image attribute

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I am parsing an XML RSS feed in PHP and all is going good...but there's one attribute I can't get.

I have this XML as an example:

```html
<itunes:explicit>Yes</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:duration>3353</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:image href="https://d3t3ozftmdmh3i.cloudfront.net/staging/podcast_uploaded_episode400/14815155/c10417f6f80f6529.jpeg"/>
            <itunes:episode>43</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
```

I'm parsing it with this code:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) { 

  
    echo("\n\t<itunes:duration>" . $item->children('itunes', true)->duration ."</itunes:duration>    

     \n\t<itunes:duration>" . $item->children('itunes', true)->duration ."</itunes:duration> 

     \n\t<itunes:image>" . $item->children('itunes', true)->image ."</itunes:image> 

     
     \n\t<itunes:episode>" . $item->children('itunes', true)->episode ."</itunes:episode>   
     
     \n\t<itunes:episodeType>" . $item->children('itunes', true)->episodeType ."</itunes:episodeType>   
     
     </item>";
```

}

Four of the five values work (which is driving me nuts. If none worked, I'd get it).  For some reason the "itunes:image" tag won't pull.  I thought maybe "image" is a reserved word, so I also tried

```
     \n\t<itunes:image>" . $item->children('itunes:image') ."</itunes:image>
```

but it also returns nothing.

How can I grab that image element?

Comment: Have you tried `$item->children('itunes', true)->image['href']`? You want the attribute `href`, not the node value like the other elements.

Comment: Good catch. That should fix it.... but it didn't.  I'm not sure why but it's still returning nothing. And the source does have a value for href in the itunes:image tag.  Any other thoughts?